# Live data binding with ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've got a Repeater control which is bound to a DataTable. When I update the data table the rendered repeater control is not updated. What can I use so an update to the data table causes the repeater control to be updated?

Here's the code for the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" >
<HeaderTemplate><ol id="selectable"></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
      <li style= "<%# Eval(@"STYLE").ToString()  %>"  > <%# Eval(@"ITEM").ToString()  %> </li> 
</ItemTemplate> 
<FooterTemplate></ol></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am updating the "STYLE" column in the data table in the code behind.

Thanks

Comment: Which language do you use? C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

After you update the DataTable, you need to DataBind the repeater again after the data have been changed in order to show the updated content:

```
// Change the data
Repeater3.DataSource = newDataTable;
Repeater3.DataBind();
```

In contrast to WinForms, there is no permanent connection between the data source and the bound control in ASP.NET. That's why you need to explicitly renew the data binding once changes have occurred.

Comment: Tried that. The repeater now has the updated data source but the data has not flowed through to the page. How can I get the changes made to the repeater's data source to be reflected on the page?

Comment: @user3213700:what do you mean by "flowed through the page"? Does the repeater not show the new data? In a PostBack, you have to reload the data, apply the changes and then bind the repeater to the data again.

Comment: In the Page_Load method I do have    

   `Repeater3.DataSource = newDataTable;
   Repeater3.DataBind();`
   
When I walk through the code in debug mode I can see that the repeater is binding and it is causing the following line
   
   `<li style= "<%# Eval(@"STYLE").ToString()  %>"  > <%# Eval(@"ITEM").ToString()  %> </li>`
   
to be evaluated again but the page itself is still showing the old data.

Comment: @user3213700: when do you change the data? If you change the data after the Repeater is bound, the changes won't be reflected. Have you verified in the debugger that newDataTable contains the updated data?